# VBA connection string to IBM AS400 in Office365 64-bit

Tags: office365, 64-bit, connection-string, ibm-midrange

The following VBA connection string works fine in MS Office 2016 32-bit:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
str_400Connect = "Provider=IBMDA400.DataSource.1;Data Source=" & Trim(aDSN) & ";Initial Catalog=SYS01;User Id=" & Trim(aUID) & ";Password=" & Trim(aPassword) & ";"
    
Set gConnect_AS400 = New ADODB.Connection
With gConnect_AS400
     .ConnectionString = gStr_400Connect
     .Open
End With
```

However, after I have upgraded to Office365 64-bit, (other components remain unchanged, e.g. IBM drivers etc), the above connection string is failed to run and return the error message:
**"Provider cannot be found. it may not be properly installed."**

Do you know what provider can I use in the connection string for 64bit office? Thank you very much.

Comment: it seems you need to install a proper driver for the x64 platform

Comment: Thanks. Actually we have already installed with 64-bit IBM drivers. However, I don't know how to "force" the VBA codes to use the 64-bit driver. It seems by default, the VBA will use the 32-bit driver.

Comment: Finally, the problem has been resolved. It is true that the driver is not correct for 64 bit Office. I need to re-install an older IBM i Access version

Comment: Great, I've posted this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a proper driver for the x64 platform.

Comment: thanks for your hint. It solved the problem after re-install the IBM i access driver.